# How to redirect printstream to JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, io, system, jtextarea

I am writing a pattern generator and here is the chief code (character for pattern and steps are provided by JTextFields):

```
String chstrin=ch.getText();
char c=chstrin.charAt(0);
int n = Integer.parseInt(st.getText()) ;

for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < i*2-1; ++k)
        System.out.print(c);

    System.out.println();
}
```

How do I redirect the output to a JTextArea by the name of "res"?
I did read about System.setOut and PipedOutput on both StackOverflow and the net but can't understand a single line of code.
Can anyone help me out? Please use JTextArea res as your output.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any problem with the above code? Is it relevent to the question about the `JTextArea`? Or do you just not know how to set text in the `JTextArea`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know about how to send the output to JTextArea in this case. I did try res.append(""+c) but it completely fails. Please help @peeskillet

Comment: Take a look at my answer. You should use the `append` method to generate continuous lines of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the JTextArea 's name is res ; then :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < i*2-1; ++k)
       res.setText(res.getText()+c);

    res.setText(res.getText()+"\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for the delay. Happy now @iShaalan ?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is send the text to a `JTextArea` instead of the console, just do something like this

```
JTextArea res = new JTextArea();  

....

String chstrin=ch.getText();
char c=chstrin.charAt(0);
int n = Integer.parseInt(st.getText()) ;
for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < i*2-1; ++k) {
        res.append(String.valueOf(c));
    }
    res.append("\n");
}
```

The `append` method with allow you to add continuous text to the `JTextArea`. If you use `setText()`. It will rewrite the text area.

Also consider line wrapping. You may want to wrap the lines of Text. To do so, do this

```
JTextArea res = new JTextArea(); 
res.setLineWrap(true);
res.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Comment: fails to recognise res.append(c);  says char cannot be converted to string.

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(c)`.  `res.append(String.valueOf(c));`